# Incompatible Identical Types

Tags: typescript

On several occasions, I have encountered an unusual type error, in the following form:

```
Type 'SomeType<SomeGeneric>' is not assignable to type 'SomeType<SomeGeneric>'.
```

The weird part is that, from what I can tell, the two types seem to be identical. They are both from the same module. It's just that the module exists in two places. It exists at the top-level of `node_modules`, and also exists as a dependency of another module. TypeScript believes that the two types are incompatible, even though, upon inspection of the source of both types, they would seem to be identical. The versions of both modules are the same.

Another weird aspect of this issue is that while the type error appears in the standalone TypeScript compiler, it does not appear in [Atom](https://atom.io/) using [`ide-typescript`](https://atom.io/packages/ide-typescript).

Is there any reason why this might be the case?

This is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "lib":
    [
        "es2015",
        "es2017"
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths":
    {
        "common/*": ["../Common/*"]
    },
    "watch": true
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a piece of code to reproduce the error?

Comment: The module that I am currently encountering this with is `rethinkdb-ts`. I'm using a private module which has `rethinkdb-ts` as a dependency. I'll see if I can construct a public module which acts in a similar manner.

Comment: I've attempted to reproduce it here, but the type error does not occur: https://github.com/ChrisTalman/incompatible-identical-types.

Comment: The error also seems to no longer occur in one of my projects. It may have been that the dependency had a different `rethinkdb-ts` version to the project. I'm not sure.

Comment: Hello @ChrisTalman, did you find the answer to this question? I'm encountering the same issue today.

Comment: Hey Dragos. I'm still not sure precisely why this happens. I make sure that all the dependencies are the same version. Sometimes a dependency of a dependency can mess it up. Occasionally I have to do an `as` assertion.